# Diff between values in different rows

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

MariaDB version 10.4.10.

I have a stock scraper script that fetches stock data every hour and inserts it into a MySQL database. The database structure is similar to this:

```
stocks( time_fetched DATETIME, fetch_id INT, name VARCHAR, price INT )
```

And some example data:

```
**time_fetched          fetch_id        name        price**
2020-03-10 09:00:00     1               stock1      10
2020-03-10 09:00:00     1               stock2      15
2020-03-10 10:00:00     2               stock1      12
2020-03-10 10:00:00     2               stock2      20
2020-03-10 11:00:00     3               stock1      8
2020-03-10 11:00:00     3               stock2      18
```

I want a way to get price change for each stock between, say, stocks fetched at 09:00 and 10:00, or between 09:00 and 11:00. Something like this (pseudo code):

```
SELECT *, DIFF( current_price, price_one_hour_ago) AS change_1h, DIFF( current_price, price_two_hours_ago) AS change_2h
```

Is it possible to do this directly in MySQL? I am using a PHP script to display the data, so I might have to resort to do it in PHP instead.

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect for this sample data.

Comment: see also: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/lag/ https://mariadb.com/kb/en/lead/

Comment: Do you have gaps in the times?  If so, how do you handle that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` to generate prices delayed by 1 or 2 hours, and then compute the changes using those values (potentially using `COALESCE` to make `NULL` values into `0`):

```
WITH prices AS (
  SELECT time_fetched, name, price,
         LAG(price, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY time_fetched) AS price_1h,
         LAG(price, 2) OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY time_fetched) AS price_2h
  FROM stocks
)
SELECT time_fetched, name, price,
       COALESCE(price - price_1h, 0) AS change_1h,
       COALESCE(price - price_2h, 0) AS change_2h
FROM prices
```

Output:

```
time_fetched            name    price   change_1h   change_2h
2020-03-10 09:00:00     stock1  10      0           0
2020-03-10 10:00:00     stock1  12      2           0
2020-03-10 11:00:00     stock1  8       -4          -2
2020-03-10 09:00:00     stock2  15      0           0
2020-03-10 10:00:00     stock2  20      5           0
2020-03-10 11:00:00     stock2  18      -2          3
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=02d51b7515efcb6da5f0efee145cbd1d) also showing query results without `COALESCE`.

Comment: Wow, that's great, thank you. I never used the window functions before, they seem super useful. Thanks again!